# Is the function $\,f(x, y) = x-y\,$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, real-numbers

Is the function $\,\,f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $$f(x,y)=x-y,$$ closed?

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f$ is not closed:

Take
$$
F=\left\{(x,y):y\ge x+\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right\}.
$$
Then $y>x$, for all $(x,y)\in F$, and hence $0\not\in f(F)$. But $0\in\overline{f(F)}$,
as
$$
\left(n,n+\frac{1}{1+n^2}\right)\in F,
$$
and thus
$$
x-y=\frac{1}{1+n^2}\in f(F).
$$

Comment: What is $ (n , n + \frac{1}{1+n^2} ) $ and how do you know $x - y = \frac{1}{1+n^2} $ ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on your reasoning ? It is extremely hard to follow.

Comment: $a_n = \left (n,n+ \frac{1}{1+n^2} \right)$ is a sequence whose image under $f$ approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Since the image approaches but does not contain $0$, the image is open. However $F$ itself is closed. This demonstrates that $f$ is not closed.

Comment: The image being open does not guarantee that the imagine is not closed.

Comment: Good point. Here though, $0$ belongs to the closure but not to the the set. Since the closure is larger than the set, the set cannot be closed.

Answer (score 7):

the image of the closed set $\{x^2-y^2=1\}$ is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$, not closed.